# Falling Robot Framework tests in GitHub actions

Tags: github-actions, robotframework

1. I have a problem with run Robot framework tests via GitHub actions. All these test are running without problem in visual studio code, Selenium library is there imported,  but in GitHub actions  they all fall.

I have try to run tests trhoug CI and  All test are fallen because of Selenium Library.

```
   // ..Run robot  TESTS
==============================================================================
    Create board and list and use Drag and Drop                           | FAIL |
    No keyword with name 'Open Browser' found.
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TESTS.Drag and drop :: Create board and list and use Drag and Drop    | FAIL |
    1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
    ==============================================================================
    [ ERROR ] Error in file '/home/runner/work/Trelloapp-Robot-Framework-tests/Trelloapp-Robot-Framework-tests/TESTS/Sign_in.robot' on line 4: Importing library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SeleniumLibrary'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      None
    PYTHONPATH:
      /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.15/x64/bin
      /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.15/x64/lib/python39.zip
      /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.15/x64/lib/python3.9
      /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.15/x64/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
      /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.15/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages
    TESTS.Sign in :: Sipn up to app and check Signup                              
    ==============================================================================
    Sipn up to app and check Sign up                                      | FAIL |
    No keyword with name 'Open Browser' found.
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TESTS.Sign in :: Sipn up to app and check Signup                      | FAIL |
    1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
    ==============================================================================
    [ ERROR ] Error in file '/home/runner/work/Trelloapp-Robot-Framework-tests/Trelloapp-Robot-Framework-tests/TESTS/Sign_out.robot' on line 4: Importing library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SeleniumLibrary'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      None
    PYTHONPATH:
      /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.15/x64/bin
      /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.15/x64/lib/python39.zip
      /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.15/x64/lib/python3.9
      /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.15/x64/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
      /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.15/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages
    TESTS.Sign out :: Sipn up to app and check signup                             
    ==============================================================================
    Sign up, check if the user is logged in and Sign out and check if ... | FAIL |
    No keyword with name 'Open Browser' found.
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TESTS.Sign out :: Sipn up to app and check signup                     | FAIL |
    1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
    ==============================================================================
    TESTS                                                                 | FAIL |
    10 tests, 0 passed, 10 failed
    ==============================================================================
    Output:  /home/runner/work/Trelloapp-Robot-Framework-tests/Trelloapp-Robot-Framework-tests/output.xml
    Log:     /home/runner/work/Trelloapp-Robot-Framework-tests/Trelloapp-Robot-Framework-tests/log.html
    Report:  /home/runner/work/Trelloapp-Robot-Framework-tests/Trelloapp-Robot-Framework-tests/report.html
    Error: Process completed with exit code 10.
```

## This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

// ..

```
name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "main" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      #python and robotframework setup
      - name: Set up Python 3.9
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: 3.9
          cache: 'pip'
          
      - name: Install python dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
      
      - name: Run tests
        run: |
                 robot  TESTS

// ..
```

Comment: We need to see the content of requirements.txt (is SeleniumLibrary there?) `pip install -r requirements.txt` (And then the browser and its webdriver, are they installed?)

Comment: What @helio said Or just switch "python" and "pip" to "python3" and "pip3"

Comment: Hi. switching python and pip to python3 and pip3 does not work. I am new in Robot Framework.   Here is inside of requirements.txt                                              
                                                                                                                         
selenium >= 4.0.0
robotframework >= 3.2.2
robotframework-pythonlibcore >= 2.2.1

Comment: @Lukas It is missing in the requirements.txt the SeleniumLibrary: `robotframework-seleniumlibrary`. See the library page at https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `requirements.txt` file is missing some dependency.

The quickest way is to see what Robot Framework libraries you have installed locally. Just use `pip list` and look for all `robotframework-...` packages. Then add those to your `requirements.txt` file.

Now, when installing dependencies in a GitHub job, all Robot Framework keywords you have locally should be also available while running the job.